# How to make Azure DataLake as a Camel endpoint

Tags: java, azure, apache-camel, azure-data-lake

I have a project using Camel(java). I am retrieving data from one source and am sending it to one endpoint(using the .to() ). I need to also send it to Azure DataLake. How would I go about this. I donot see any camel components for DataLake. Would I have to make my own component?

Comment: Please go through following links http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html

Comment: another way https://dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-camel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, today you would have to create your own Camel component.

There isn't currently a [Camel component (link)](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) for Azure Data Lake Store.

There's a way you could give feedback if this is something you'd like to see officially supported: see the [UserVoice page (link)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake) for Data Lake.